# How to close only current popup in Javascript and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form as a popup and I want to add a cancel button to close current popup. I tried many ways to do it but it is not closing

```
 <form id="overlay_form_uploadGenFile" action="/crm/saveGeneralFile" method="POST" class="overlay_form" style="display:none" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1 style="font-size: 2em">Edit uploaded file</h1>
            <input type="hidden" name="fileId" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{userId}}"/>
            <span>Category:</span><span id="file-filter-by">Filter by:</span> <select name="fileCategoryTagId" onchange="populatePopupCategories(this);"></select>
            <div id="file-category-select"><select name="fileCategoryId" onchange="getShareWithIntegrationServicesForPopup(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"></select></div><br/>
            Current File: <input type="text" name="filename" class="currentFile"/> (change it to rename the file)<br/><br/>
            To replace <input type="file" name="fileData" class="replaceFile" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="editableByHR" class="editableHR"/> Editable by HR
            <input type="checkbox" name="sharedWithEmployee" /> Shared With Employee <br/>
            Notes <textarea name="notes" class="fileUpdateNotes"></textarea><br/><br/>

            <br/>
            <div class="integrationServicesContainerHolder">
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%">
                <div align="left" style="float: left">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" align="left" class="submitFileUpdateButton"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closeFunction" align="left" class="submitFileUpdateButton"/>
                </div>
                <div align="right" style="float: right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" align="right" class="submitFileUpdateButton"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and the function side is

```
function closeFunction() {
    $('#overlay_form_uploadGenFile').hide();
}
```

I have tried `.dialog('hide')` and `.modal('hide')` as well but still not working. If I try self.closeAll then it is closing all tab. How can I close only this form dialog popup ?

edit: ok I put `$('#overlay_form_uploadGenFile').fadeOut(100);` and problem is solved almost... I need immediate close because fadeOut is blocking me for calling other functions due to asynchronous calls.

Comment: The IDs do not match. In the function it is #overlay_form_downloadGenFile but the popup has #overlay_form_uploadGenFile.

Comment: I have edited that. still its not closing

Comment: fadeOut can take callback function as a second parameter
$('#overlay_form_uploadGenFile').fadeOut(100, function completefadeOutCallback() { // to do after fade out })

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the `break` function. That will exit the current loop.